# Heroku Custom domain (Namecheap) is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, namecheap, custom-domain

That's my first time dealing with custom domain. I have Rails app hosted on Heroku. I set up custom domain in Heroku app's settings: 
[image]
Configured app's DNS provider (Namecheap) to point to the DNS target. Already contacted them, they said that I pointed my domain to Heroku correctly.
[image] 
But my domain "polina.io" is still not working. And I don't understand why.

[image]

When I run `$ dig CNAME www.polina.io` in terminal to check changes, everything looks fine:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> CNAME www.polina.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65173
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.polina.io.         IN  CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.polina.io.      251 IN  CNAME   hidden-alligator-62pta0x140xhvkwsl9336sfc.herokudns.com.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 115.178.58.10#53(115.178.58.10)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 21 14:56:22 +07 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone run to the same problem, maybe it will help.

I fixed my problem with adding SSL Certificate (not sure if that was important) and adding not only www.domainexample.com, but just root domain as well (domainexample.com):

```
$ heroku domains:add polina.io
$ heroku domains:wait 'polina.io'
```